# Where is the "add product logic" in smart category rule - Magento 2 EE

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, category, category-products, magento2-enterprise

I need to alter the logic of "add product in a category" based on category rule.

[image]

**My effort:**

After add rule, When I save category, it redirects to `http://host/admin/catalog/category/save/key/cae5eaa5332d3c8a4be400eb667530bfba2727445ce1a072d5f006f4a9f10be4/` but in that controller I'm not seeing any add product logic, in that controller dispatch event `catalog_category_prepare_save` while check I found one observer `vendor/magento/module-visual-merchandiser/Observer/CategorySaveMerchandiserData.php` are listening to this event, I have checked that observer too but I can't found where it is the add product logic.

Please help me to identify.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried wrong way. Try following way:

Open **vendor/magento/module-visual-merchandiser/Observer/CatalogCategorySaveBefore.php** 
Following line actually build this according to rule.

```
$this->categoryBuilder->rebuildCategory($category);
```

Now go to **vendor/magento/module-visual-merchandiser/Model/Category/Builder.php**

Following line build this:

```
$this->rules->applyAllRules($category, $collection);
```

Now finally open **vendor/magento/module-visual-merchandiser/Model/Rules.php**

And check here:

```
public function applyAllRules(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection
) {
    ......
}
```